# Rebranding Wordpress Android app for the self hosted blog

Tags: android, wordpress

I just downloaded the source of wordpress app. I am on the process of rebranding the wordpress app (icons & lebels) for my self hosted site. I was wondering, if there is a process / configuration option to remove the wordpress links & wordpress blogging options from my app. It doesn't make sense for the user to download my app from market place & go to wordpress site with it.

THIS IS A GENERIC ANDROID QUESTION:

I want the users be able to use both the default wordpress app & my self hosted app. However, for that, I think I need to change the package name in the android manifest and thus refactor all the old package names of all the java class. But then I will loose the ability to sync & get update of the latest build of the wordpress app.

**Is there a way I can install the same code with the same package (as a different application) without conflicting with the wordpress app ?**

***Can anyone point me to the direction where I can find more details on the application namespace / package name conflicts?***

Comment: I don't quite get it. What is that Wordpress app? A native app or is it a web-based app? What updates are you talking about Market updates?

Comment: its an android app for accessing/managing wordpress blogs from your phone.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you must do to rebrand:

1. You just need to edit the AndroidManifest.xml and change references to Wordpress.
2. Change icons (/res/drawable) that show Worpress logo.
3. Change strings (/res/values & /res/values-xx) that say "wordpress".
4. Search the sources if there are any occurences of "wordpress" in Strig literals.
5. You need to change the package name of classes. This is trivial. Use refactoring in your IDE.

Answer: package name must be unique - apps in the market can be searched by their package name: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

**NOTE:** Wordpress Android app is licensed under GPL - you will have to make your sources available under GPL to the public.